# Is it possible to access components of the uut in VHDL Testbench?

Tags: testing, vhdl

I want to write a testbench for a module that instantiates several components but has no significant outputs. To test the correctness I'd have to access variables of components of the uut. At least being able to access variables of the uut would be helpful.

I would imagine that to work a little like this:

```
uut: top_module port map(
              i_clk => clk,
              i_reset => reset
      );
testbench: process
begin
    wait for CLK_PERIOD;
    report  STD_LOGIC'image(top_module.flag) severity note;
end process;
```

Of course I can write the testbench in a way that it replaces the top module but then I wouldn't be able to test that model. Expanding the output of the top module/uut is also not really an option.

Comment: The answer is more than one testbench : unit tests for the components, and a top level test to verify externally visible functionality. These testbenches can share a common library to maximise reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VHDL 2008 you can use the new [external names](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_ease/#hierarchicalnames) syntax:

```
alias int1 << signal .tb_top.u_ioc.int1 : std_logic >>;
```

With an earlier VHDL standard you have to use vendor-specific tools, e.g. *signal_spy* for Questa/ModelSim.

Another method would be to write your testbench at a lower level, e.g. connect your sub-components inside the testbench instead of testing the highest-level entity.

Comment: For [aldec](https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/articles/1123) it is signal_agent. Unfortunately I use Xilinx ISE which doesn't have VHDL-2008 and I couldn't find a vendor specific tool. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Perhaps then you should file a bug report against Xilinx so they realize they are failing to meet industry expectations.

Comment: Xilinx (Vivado) claims to support VHDL-2008 but only partially in Synth and not in xSim ... So you can write code that is not supported by all tools of the same toolchain :).